# Laravel 5.8 Passing parameter to view returned undefined

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5.8

I want to pass the username to the url in the browser as in "/profile/{username that's logged in here}". But to test things out i tried to pass id first.
What's wrong with this is not when i press the actual link. The problem occurs when i tried to access just the welcome page.

I've called the route in the view and passed the correct param 'user' to it but it's still giving me an undefined variable error.

here's the route

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/profile/{user}', 'ProfilesController@index')->name('profile.show');
```

The ProfilesController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProfilesController extends Controller
{
    public function index($user)
    {
        $user = User::find($user);
        return view('home', [
            'user' => $user,
        ]);
    }
}
```

The welcome blade:

```
<div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
            @if (Route::has('login'))
                <div class="top-right links">
                    @auth
                        <a href="{{ route('profile.show', $user) }}">Home</a>
                    @else
                        <a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>

                        @if (Route::has('register'))
                            <a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a>
                        @endif
                    @endauth
                </div>
            @endif

            <div class="content">
                <div class="title m-b-md">
                    gramClone
                </div>
                <p class="content">
                    where IG pics get to be shittier.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

the home blade it calls after pressing home link:

```
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 p-5">
            <img src="/png/logo.png" alt="logo" style="height: 6rem; width: 6rem;" class="float-right rounded-circle">
        </div>
        <div class="col-8 pt-5">
            <div><h1>{{$user->username}}</h1></div>
            <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="pr-5"><strong>number here</strong> posts</div>
                <div class="pr-5"><strong>number here</strong> followers</div>
                <div class="pr-5"><strong>number here</strong> following</div>
            </div>
            <div class="pt-4 font-weight-bold">Bio Summary Here</div>
            <div>Bio Here</div>
            <div><a href="#">Link Here</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row pt-5">
        <div class="col-4"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1566624790190-511a09f6ddbd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" alt="" class="w-100"></div>
        <div class="col-4"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544127715-bafd09df7c52?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" alt="" class="w-100"></div>
        <div class="col-4"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1566592952746-15ea1f1a4133?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=653&q=80" alt="" class="w-100"></div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Some of my friends said it's cause i have to put the param at get'/' as well but when i tried it, it gave me the previous error of unpassed param again.

Please help me with this, i've been on overflow for 3 hours already and still got no actual answer to this.

Comment: Does the value show in controller?

Comment: `dd($user)` in welcome.blade.php. See if you get the data here.

Comment: How do you mean? @shihab

Comment: what is value of ```$user``` in controller. you can ```dd($user)``` to see value

Comment: like this right?              <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
            <?php if(Route::has('login')): ?>
                <div class="top-right links">
                    <?php if(auth()->guard()->check()): ?>
 
                        <?php echo e(dd($user)); ?>        It still gives me an undefined variable error.

Comment: that one is from the error so it's the fully pared version. my actual code is just {{dd($user)}} after my route calling(commented out) @shihab

Answer (score 0):

Found out the problem after commenting out my route calling in the welcome blade, apparently it's the @auth making things freaky. After some quick googling i found out that apparently you can't just say `route('profile.show', $user)` if you have an @auth there.

You need to call it like this: `auth()->user()`.